# Equivalent of bash's `source` command in Powershell?

Tags: bash, powershell

To run a bash script line-by-line (so as to preserve environment variables, for instance), one does the following:

```
$ . myscript.sh
```

Or:

```
$ source myscript.sh
```

I have a PowerShell script that - among other things - sets the value of the prompt via [function](http://mshforfun.blogspot.com/2006/05/perfect-prompt-for-windows-powershell.html) called `prompt`. Simply running this script (".\myscript.ps1") does not change the prompt. However, running function line-by-line *as a command* does.

So what I effectively need is something like the `source` command for PowerShell. Is it possible?

**EDIT**: Should this post be moved to Stackoverflow?

**Clarification 1**: Since I run this function only on a need basis (i.e., not for every powershell session and/or always), I do not want to store in my powershell startup profile.

Comment: Note: your two Bash commands are different. You probably didn't mean to have the dot in the second one or you meant both of them to have "./" (current directory) at the beginning of the script name.

Comment: Fixed it (by removing the dot)

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You can "[dot source](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scripts?view=powershell-6&viewFallbackFrom=powershell-Microsoft.PowerShell.Core#script-scope-and-dot-sourcing)" in PowerShell as well. You just need to make sure that you specify the full path. So, if the script you want to load is in the local directory you would do:

```
PS C:\>. .\myscript.ps1
```

Comment: THIS is the right answer :) dot sourcing in PowerShell works pretty much just like in Bash

Comment: I had no idea you could do that.  nice.

Comment: Whoa! How come I didn't try it before? :)

Comment: Is there anyway this could be done with an existing cmd script?  Have a cmd script execution result in the powershell environment being modified?

Comment: What if you need to run a `.bat` file and modify the environment?

Comment: @chloe that's a whole other ball of wax. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20078088/4304

Comment: @zdan Seriously? Parse the `.bat` file? I think I'll just stop using PowerShell and go back to the DOS command prompt.

Comment: is there any way this can be done with words -- i.e. "source" -- as the "." is a pretty special char that varies in all contexts, and anything relying on this will look like chicken scratch

Comment: I would not say local dir but dir that is in the same dir as your invoking scriptr.

Comment: @chris regarding your question with `source`, in pwsh7: `The term 'source' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.`

Comment: @Timo i.e. stands for "id est", or "that is", and is a shorthand way to relate something similar,  I.e. the Bourne Again Shell (Bash)'s keyword "source", which performs this function. This is consistent across all of the shell languages (AFAIK), and PowerShell was written specifically to be similar to them and allow Windows to compete with Unix and Linux at the integration layer (the system shell).  So if it doesn't have "source" it probably *should* given its mission scope.